# Getting height of a page

Tags: nativescript

I've got a page that has an action bar and a layout that takes the rest of the page. I'd like to know the height of the rest of the page - that's SCREEN_HEIGHT - STATUS_BAR_HEIGHT - ACTION_BAR_HEIGHT.

I can get SCREEN_HEIGHT via platform.screen.mainScreen.heightDIPs.

How can I get the height of the STATUS_BAR and ACTION_BAR.

When I try to do a height or getMeasuredHeight(), I get 0.

Comment: android: https://gist.github.com/hamakn/8939eb68a920a6d7a498 I don't have time to help translate to .ts or .js but that's one approach for android.

Answer (score 3):

Using the answer from Brad, here's the ts code

```
       let resource_id = application.android.foregroundActivity.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");

    if ( resource_id > 0 )
        console.log( "status_bar_height=" + application.android.foregroundActivity.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resource_id) );

    //  android.content.res.TypedArray

    let array = application.android.foregroundActivity.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes( [ android.R.attr.actionBarSize ] );

    console.log( "actionBarHeight=" + array.getDimension(0,0) );
```

Looks like the values returned is the actual pixels.

If you want the DIP values - divide by platformModule.screen.mainScreen.scale.